# How to get an icecast header with dart

Tags: dart, httprequest, icecast

im trying to get icecast metadata with dart on the server side of things.

i have an object with a method to retrive the metadata.

to get the metadata i need to send a HttpRequest to the icecast server with a special header.
If its a propper icecast server, i should get a response header with the key/value pair **"icy-metaint", "offset"**

my dart code so far.

```dart
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    print(Uri.parse(this.src));
    client.getUrl(Uri.parse(this.src))
    .then((HttpClientRequest request) {
        request.headers.add(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36");
        request.headers.add("Icy-MetaData", "1");
    })
    .then((HttpClientResponse response) {

    });
```

but now i dont know how to actually send the request or if its even the right approach.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to close the request to get it actually sent.

```dart
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    print(Uri.parse(this.src));
    client.getUrl(Uri.parse(this.src))
    .then((HttpClientRequest request) {
        request.headers.add(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36");
        request.headers.add("Icy-MetaData", "1");
        return request.close(); // <= close the request
    })
    .then((HttpClientResponse response) {
});
```

Have you considered using Client from the http package? (like shown here [How to do POST in Dart command line HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491543))

Comment: Thanks, with your suggestion i could get it to work. You actually need to retrun the request.close() to send the request and populate the response.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example (with the suggestion from: Günter Zöchbauer)

```dart
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.getUrl(Uri.parse(this.src))
    .then((HttpClientRequest request) {
        request.headers.add(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36");
        request.headers.add("Icy-MetaData", "1");
        return request.close();
    })
    .then((HttpClientResponse response) {
        if(response.headers.value("icy-metaint") != null) {
            this.offset = int.parse(response.headers.value("icy-metaint"));
        }
        print(offset.toString());
    });
```